# В TURBO C/C++ написать обращение к ячейки памяти микропроцессора с сегментом 9000 и смещением 0040 и записать из этой ячейки значение в txt файл

Tags: c++, c, указатели, память, dos

```
//#include <windows.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <math.h >
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
//using namespace std;
void main();
void main  (void)
{
//unsigned int wseq, woff, w1off;
//wseq =0x9000;
//woff =0x0040;
//w1off = 0x0020;
void   *pAUXBuff, *pOutBuff;
pAUXBuff =(void *)  MK_FP(0x9000, 0x0040);
pOutBuff =(void *)  MK_FP(0x9000, 0x0020);
//pAUXBuff = (WORD far *)(wseq*16+woff);
//pOutBuff = (WORD far*)(wseq*16+w1off);
int i=0;
while (i<=100)
{
if((*(pOutBuff+0x9)) %2 == 0)
{
 ofstream  out;
 out.open("C:\\Desktop\\CPU.txt", ios ::app);
 //if (out.open(const char*))
 //{
// out.flags(ios::hex(ios::showbase));
 out<<"Znachenie sin DPR UM"<<endl;
 out<<(long)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA6))<<endl;
 out<<"Znachenie cos DPR UM"<<endl;
 out<<(long)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA7))<<endl;

 out<<"Znachenie sin DPR AZ"<<endl;
 out<<(long)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA8))<<endl;
 out<<"Znachenie cos DPR AZ"<<endl;
 out<<(long)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA9))<<endl;
 }
// out.close();
 cout<<"Read the value angel ACP-DPR" << endl;
 cout.flags(ios::hex|ios::showbase);
 cout<<"Value angle sin UM"<<endl;
   cout<<(long)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA6))<<endl;
   cout<<"Value angle cos UM"<<endl;
   cout<<(long)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA9))<<endl;
   i++;
   if(i==100)
      {
      break;
   }
   }
  // return 0;
   }
```

[image: Скриншот с ошибками компилятора]

Comment: Добрый день.Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так (я новичок).Есть MS DOS в ней работают программы микропроцессор каждые 2мс считывает значения датчиков углов поворота антенн  и после АЦП записывает в память с адресом 0x9000 и смещение 0x0040 и так далее.Мне нужно обратиться к  этой ячейки и записать ее в файл txt, чтобы проверить правильно ли работает АЦП.

Comment: Первая ошибка очевидна: вы пытаетесь разыменовывать указатель `void*`: `*(pOutBuff+0x9)` Разыменовывать можно указатель на конкретный тип. Ячейка памяти ровно одна? Тогда это `unsigned char*`. Все эти `A6` и иже с ним — у вас случайно русская `A` вместо английской не затесалась? И еще — насколько я помню (ох как давно это было), нужно компилировать в модели памяти large? что ли, и указатели использовать с ключевым словом `far`. Но тут за давностью лет могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Номера строк в ошибках не соответствуют исходному коду.

Comment: Доброе утро!Так ячеек несколько, нужные мне это два буфера в которых есть обмен pAUXBuff (сегмент 0x9000 смещение 0x0040)  и pOutBuff((сегмент 0x9000 смещение 0x0020) в них есть ячейки с данными это (pAUXBuff+0xA6) , (pAUXBuff+0xA9), (pAUXBuff+0xA8), (pAUXBuff+0xA9).Из них надо считать в файл.Помогите пожалуйста уже просто месяц ничего не могу найти сделать ,чтобы программа корректно компилировалась.

Comment: Буквы английский, почему ошибка в числах шестнадцатеричных не пойму.Запись правильная же.Если можно в виде кода я просто не знаю, что исправлять.

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы тот, для кого предназначен комментарий, получил о нем уведомление — добавляйте @ с его именем, типа @andrew163. Что до конкретного ответа с кодом — ну очень не хочется возиться с поиском древнего борланда, его установкой и воспоминаниями... :( Но вот еще одна несуразность: `(pAUXBuff+0xA6)` — `pAUXBuff` — это указатель на `void`, к нему арифметика указателей неприменима.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.Буду пробовать.@Harry

Comment: Да код скомпилировался без ошибок(очень благодарен вам).Есть датчик положения ротора, срабатывает аппаратное прерывание IRQ7 каждые 2мс формируются данные sin и cos углов этих датчиков(счетчик миллисекунд находится по адресу*(pOutBuff+0x9) ), а сами данные вот в эти ячейках записываются (pAUXBuff+0xA6) , (pAUXBuff+0xA9), (pAUXBuff+0xA8), (pAUXBuff+0xA9) мне их и надо разыменовать и  записать в файл и потом анализировать. Я так вот понял.Микропроцессор CPU-188 -5 на котором работает это  и стоит плата счетчиков /таймеров 5300@Harry

Comment: Данные в этих ячейках 12-ти разрядные, я хочу записать их в шестнадцатеричной системе и всё. @Harry

Comment: Непонятно, как они у вас лежат. Это не описание - 12 разрядов. Это могут быть 24 бит в трех или четырех байтах, little-endian или big-endian. Вобщем, пока не будет точного ТЗ, ответ будет один - ХЗ. Особенно если учесть, что они у вас с какими-то странными (и повторяющимися) смещениями — A6, A9, A8, A9 - что-то тут точно не так.

Comment: Данные 16-разрядные.  SinA6 =(short int)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA6));CosA7 =(short int)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA7)); SinA8 =(short int)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA8));CosA9 =(short int)(*(pAUXBuff+0xA9)); Это из резидентной программы, которая работает в Dos.@Harry

Comment: wSeg=0x9000;
wOff=0x0000;
pGlobalBuff=(byte far*)MK_FP(wSeg,wOff);
// получить адрес приемного буфера  InBuff        16x2 байт
pInBuff=(word far*)pGlobalBuff;
// получить адрес передающего буфера OutBuff     16x2 байт
pOutBuff=pInBuff+16;
// получить адрес дополнительного буфера  AUXBuff 256x2 байт
pAUXBuff=pOutBuff+16;@Harry

Comment: Ну тогда замените `unsigned char` на `short int`. Судя по коду из резидента, у вас 0xA6 и прочие смещения — это номера элементов, грубо говоря, `pAUXBuff[0xA7]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем, примерно так, если нужны именно байты, а не, скажем, `int` — я же не знаю, что там и как у вас лежит в памяти. Я *только сделал код компилируемым*, а уж насчет того, что он делает что нужно...

```
unsigned char far *pAUXBuff, far *pOutBuff;
pAUXBuff = (unsigned char far *)MK_FP(0x9000, 0x0040);
pOutBuff = (unsigned char far *)MK_FP(0x9000, 0x0020);
//pAUXBuff = (WORD far *)(wseq*16+woff);
//pOutBuff = (WORD far*)(wseq*16+w1off);
int i=0;
while (i<=100)
{
```